# Exported package not resolved in Eclipse Plugin

Tags: eclipse-plugin, slf4j, osgi-bundle, logback-classic

I'm using [`org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30`](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.30/jar) and [ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3](https://search.maven.org/artifact/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic/1.2.3/jar) in one of my bundles (Maven `<packaging>eclipse-plugin`) via the project's *Target Platform* definition (i.e. another Maven project with `<packaging>eclipse-target-definition`).

The `slf4j-api` JAR's `MANIFEST.MF` contains:

```
...
Import-Package: org.slf4j.impl;version=1.6.0
```

The `logback-classic` JAR also contains the package `org.slf4j.impl` and its `MANIFEST.MF` contains:

```
...
Export-Package: ...
 ....................., org.slf4j.impl;versi
 on="1.7.25";uses:="org.slf4j,org.slf4j.spi"
...
```

If I add:

```
Import-Package: ...
 ...
 org.slf4j,
 ch.qos.logback.classic,
 org.slf4j.impl
```

to my bundle's MANIFEST.MF` only the first two are resolved. For the latter Eclipse shows the error:

> Bundle 'ch.qos.logback.slf4j' exporting package 'org.slf4j.impl' is unresolved

and the `ch.qos.logback.classic_1.2.3.v20200428-2012.jar` in  my bundle's *Plugin-Dependencies* folder shows only `ch.qos.logback.classic` package and sub-packages thereof.

Major question:

1. Why is `org.slf4j.impl` not considered exported and hence cannot be resolved?

Minor questions:

2. Where does the `Bundle-SymbolicName` in the error message come from?
3. Where does the qualifier `v20200428-2012` of `logback-classic`'s JAR in the *Target Platform* definition come from? It's `MANIFEST.MF` doesn't contain this, but just `Bundle-Version: 1.2.3`.
4. Why does `slf4j-api` import `org.slf4j.impl`? Shouldn't rely an implementation on an API and not vice versa?

### UPDATE

I found answers to 2. and 3. (not the first that this happens while writing an SO question :): It's from Eclipse itself: https://ftp.fau.de/eclipse/releases/2021-03/202103171000/plugins/

And this also leads to an answer for 1.: I'm actually not using the orignal `slf4j` and `logback` JARs but those from Eclipse and `ch.qos.logback.slf4j`'s `MANIFEST.MF` contains:

```
...
Export-Package: org.slf4j.impl;x-internal:=true;version="1.7.30";uses:
 ="org.slf4j,org.slf4j.spi"
...
```

So 5. How to get the package `org.slf4j.impl` exported/imported nevertheless?

Comment: Please improve your question instead of adding an _UPDATE_ section and provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Isn't one of the goals of SLF4J to not talk directly to the implementation?

Comment: @nitind That's what I thought, too. It has been [deactivated in v1.8.0](https://github.com/qos-ch/slf4j/commit/7a1d11ef60fe38f158c967f5630a33863ae2269c#diff-9801981279a3fa96ec808fa91c0b915bccba33451ef0eabfc53bae8e0a39de24) but it's still in v1.7.x.